# Rspec undefined method it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with my rspec code. I write some tests. I use syntax like: subject {page} and then i want to write test's in this style: it {should have_content()} but when I run rspec it show's error:

```
Failure/Error: it{ should have_content("Post associated with #{category.name}") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `it' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000007c86ea8>
```

This is my all file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Categories Pages" do
    subject {page}
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    before {sign_in user}
    let(:category) {FactoryGirl.create(:category)}
    let(:p3 )   {FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: user, content: "Foo", title: "Bar", category: category)}


    describe "Categories show page" do 
        before do 
            visit post_path(p3)
            click_link 'Test Category'
        end             

        it "should has elements" do 
            current_path.should == category_path(category)
            it{ should have_content("Post associated with #{category.name}") }
            expect(page).to have_content(p3.content)
            expect(page).to have_link(p3.title, href: post_path(p3))
            expect(page).to have_content(p3.comments.count)
            expect(page).to have_link(p3.category.name, href: category_path(p3.category))
            expect(page).to have_link(p3.user.name, href: user_path(user))
            expect(page).to have_link('All Categories', href: categories_path)
            expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Test Category'))
        end
    end
    describe "Categories index page" do 
        before do 
            visit post_path(p3)
            click_link 'Test Category'
            click_link "All Categories"
        end
        it "should have elements" do
            expect(page).to have_link('Test Category', href: category_path(category))
            expect(page).to have_selector('h1', text: 'All Categories') 
            expect(page).to have_title(full_title('All Categories'))
        end
    end
end
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have an `it` inside another `it`.

The problem is in this line:

```
it{ should have_content("Post associated with #{category.name}") }
```

Simply remove the `it`, or move it to outside of the other it block.

```
page.should have_content("Post associated with #{category.name}")
```

It is a good idea have one assertion per test. Check [better specs](http://betterspecs.org/#single)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can nest `it` blocks. Pull this line

```
it{ should have_content("Post associated with #{category.name}") }
```

out of the surrounding `it` block and make it a stand-alone test in the `describe` block.

Comment: I refactor all tests and now it's working. Thank's for help:)